# Solution for redirect to POST route Laravel

Tags: laravel, http

**SCENARIO:**

When I tried to search (POST route) a keyword, results of item will be display as lists. These items has a button (Save or UnSave) on each list. The save button, is either form POST or DELETE method and what happens is when this button clicked, either the item will SAVE or UNSAVE from the tables.

**ERROR**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

**ROUTES:**

```
Route::post('/jobseeker/jobs/search-results', [JobSeekerController::class, 'searchJobsNow'])->name('jobseeker.jobs.searchNow');

Route::post('/jobseeker/saved-jobs/{id}/save', [JobSeekerController::class, 'saveJob'])->name('jobseeker.savedJobs.save');
Route::delete('/jobseeker/saved-jobs/{id}/unsave', [JobSeekerController::class, 'unsaveJob'])->name('jobseeker.savedJobs.unsave');
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function searchJobsNow(Request $request)
{
 // codes
}

public function saveJob()
{
  // code for saving a job
   return redirect()->back();
}

public function unsaveJob()
{
  // code for unsaving a job
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@if ($job->candidateHadSavedTheJob)
  <form action="{{ route('jobseeker.savedJobs.unsave', $job->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Saved</button>
  </form>
@else
  <form action="{{ route('jobseeker.savedJobs.save', $job->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Save</button>
  </form>
@endif
```

Comment: Are you using this form, under a form?

Comment: No, it is not under another form.